# A minimal surface

Tags: minimal-surfaces

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface

Ref: The first figure with soap film at right.

What is surface parametrization or references? How is it connected to the

helicoid/catenoid ?  Thanks.

Comment: Well there is no *general* parametrization this depends on the shape of the border of the surface!

Comment: @flawr For particular border defined as a helix is there one?

Comment: I think you need on the one hand a closed border and on the other hand a criterion which you like to minimize. (There is a whole list in the WP article you cited.)

Comment: @flawr A criterion other than minimum area is needed? ;  Also one more clarification of local surface minimality.. what if we take a closed minimum perimeter line around a hole of the multiply connected Costa surface and let a minimum area film span it as a diaphragm ?